# env-file and MariaDB in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I'm trying to set up nextcloud on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with MariaDB, roughly following this example:

https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/blob/master/.examples/docker-compose/with-nginx-proxy/mariadb/apache/docker-compose.yml

My compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    env_file:
    - pi.env
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ${BASE_PATH}/db:/var/lib/mysql

  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud:apache
    env_file:
      - pi.env
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes: 
      - ${BASE_PATH}/www:/var/www
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
```

Then there is the pi.env file:

```
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secure-password
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=even-more-secure.password
MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
BASE_PATH=/tmp
```

After running `docker-compose up` from the directory the yaml and the env file are sitting in, the two containers start up fine. Alas, the database connection can not be established because the db-container only accepts a blank password (popping up a shell in the container and running `mysql -u nextcloud` without handing in a password gives me database access). Still, the $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD environment variable can be correctly echoed from the container.

If I start a mariadb-image alone with `docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secure-password`, everything behaves as expected.

Can someone point me to my mistake?

Comment: got the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I finally cured my setup some time ago. Sadly, I can not reconstruct what did the trick anymore (and my git commit messages were not as clear to my future self as I hoped they would be :D).

But it appears to me that exclusively declaring the environment variables for the database password in the pi.env file instead of the docker-compose.yaml did the trick.

My docker-compose.yaml:

```
services:
  db:
    image: jsurf/rpi-mariadb
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
    restart: always

    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    env_file:
      - pi.env

  nextcloud:
    image: nextcloud:apache
    restart: always
    container_name: nextcloud
    volumes: 
      - www:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=${VIRTUAL_HOST}
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=${VIRTUAL_HOST}
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=${LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL}
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
      - NEXTCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS=${VIRTUAL_HOST}
      - NEXTCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS=proxy
    env_file:
      - pi.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
      - default
```

pi.env:

```
MYSQL_PASSWORD=secure-password
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=even-more-secure.password
MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
```

But thank you non the less @Zanndorin!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a super late answer but I just stumbled upon this while Googling something completely unrelated.

If I recall correctly you have to tell docker-compose to actually send the ENV variables to the docker by just declaring them in environment.

```
environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_USER
```

I have never declared the .env-file in the docker-compose so maybe that already fixes that issue. I use it this way (I also have a .env file which I then sometimes override some values from).

Example from my developer MariaDB container:

```
 environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydb
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
```